# Configure error while building GUPNP

Tags: linux, configure

I'm just starting with development on linux and want to built the latest version of libGUPNP

https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GUPnP?action=show&redirect=GUPnP

Unfortunately while running configure I get this error message that I don't fully understand:

```
checking for LIBGUPNP... no
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.24.0                             gio-2.0                             gmodule-2.0                             
      gssdp-1.0 >= 0.13.0                             libsoup-2.4 >= 2.28.2                             libxml-2.0                             
      uuid) were not met:

No package 'uuid' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables LIBGUPNP_CFLAGS
and LIBGUPNP_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Does this mean, that I need a newer version of libglib? I already downloaded the latest libglib and built it, but nothing changed.

Comment: Looks like you need newer versions of `glib`, `gssdp`, `libsoup`, and `uuid`....

Comment: So I was guessing right. I but I downloaded the latest glib lib and and built and installed it but nothing has changed.

Comment: `No package 'uuid' found` You need ossp-uuid pacakge.

Comment: After several tries with different settings I now managed it to compile the whole system. thanks a lot